# Web Crawler using Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-crawler, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like Crawl 3 million web pages in a day. Due to variety of web nature - HTML, pdf etc. I need to use Selenium, Playwright etc. I noticed to use Selenium one has to build a custom container using Google DataFlow

1. Is it a good choice to use Selenium inside ParDo Fns ? Can we use a single instance of Selenium across multiple instances ?
2. Is the same applicable Playwright, should I build a custom image ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do anything in a Python DoFn that you can do from Python. Yes, I would definitely use custom containers for complex dependencies like this.

You can share instances of Selenium (or any other object) per DoFn instance by initializing it in your [setup](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.setup) method.  You can share it for the whole process by using a module-level global or something like [shared](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.utils.shared.html) (noting that it may be accessed by more than one thread at once).